# What can I use to create and read PDF files?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

I need software to create and read PDF files in my Ubuntu 14.04 like [Nitro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitro_PDF) in Windows 7?

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify what you mean by "create" PDF files?

Answer (score 1):

To view pdf you can use `evince` (comes by default with Ubuntu).
Creating pdf depends on what kind of pdf you want to make. Like `libreoffice` has option to `export as pdf`. Then almost all Image editor or graphics software has option to export as pdf. Also you can use `print to file` option of Ubuntu to make pdf out any document of image. Then there is also `pdfsam`  which you can use to marge split pdf file. And you can use `pdfedit` to edit pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Here some:

Master PDF Editor: is complete solution for creation and editing PDF and XPS files.

http://code-industry.net/pdfeditor.php

PDFedit: Free and open source editor for manipulating PDF documents. GUI version + commandline interface.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfedit/

PoDoFoBrowser: is a graphical browser and editor for the object structure of PDF files.

http://podofo.sourceforge.net/download.html

Answer (score 0):

To read pdf files:

- [evince](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/evince/)

To merge and split PDF files (with GUI):

- [PDF Mod](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pdfmod/)